# Bind data to dropdownlist from sql based on data from jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms, fullcalendar

I'm having a trouble where the data that i want to load from sql and bind to the dropdownlist based on the data in jquery. Basically, I am using fullcalendar plugin and the dropdownlist need to have the values from sql which according to the day that the user clicks.

This is the 'select' callbacks:

```
select: function (start, end) {
                            clearValues();
                            $("#PopupBookForm").modal('show');
                            $("#CDate").val(moment(start).format("YYYY/MM/DD"));
                            $("#CTime").val(moment(start).format("HH:mm:ss"));
                            $("#CEndTime").val(moment(end).format("HH:mm:ss"));

                            $("#courtDay").text(moment(start).format("dddd"));

                            getCourt(start);

                        }
```

This is the getCourt function:

```
function getCourt (currentDay)
        {
            $.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                data: "{'CurrentDay':'" + currentDay + "'}",
                url: "MRBS_BookingCourt.aspx/GetCourt"

            });
        }
```

This is from C#:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public void GetCourt(DateTime CurrentDay)
{

    InsertCourt(CurrentDay);
}

private void InsertCourt(DateTime CurrentDay)
{

    string day = CurrentDay.ToString("dddd");



    if (day.Equals("Tuesday") || day.Equals("Thursday") || day.Equals("Saturday"))
    {

        string query = "SELECT courtname FROM MRBS_Court WHERE courtCode = '100'";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem(Convert.ToString(reader["courtname"])));
            }

            reader.NextResult();


        }

        reader.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.Page.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('" + day + "');", true);
    }


}
```

So when the user clicks on tuesday or thursday or saturday on the calendar a form will pop up then the dropdownlist in the form will loads the court based on the courtcode in sql.

Here is the dropdownlist:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Much Thanks !

Comment: you can't add things to a server-side dropdown-list during an AJAX call. AJAX is not refreshing your whole page, so the ASP.NET renderer will not run. With an AJAX call you can just send a bit of data, and get a bit of data back. It doesn't re-draw the page. So your C# WebMethod needs to return a list of the items which need to go in the dropdownlist (maybe in JSON format), and then in the JavaScript you need to listen for the completion of the AJAX call, get the data returned by the server, and use it to create the options and them to the dropdownlist on the client-side.

Comment: You can find examples of this pattern in lots of tutorials etc already. Do some research and increase your understanding of how AJAX works. Then try to fix the code according to the steps I've just described. If you still get stuck after that then post your attempt and describe your issue.

Comment: e.g. here's an example https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Populate-Bind-ASPNet-DropDownList-using-jQuery-AJAX-and-JSON-in-C-and-VBNet.aspx